# Windows Server 301 redirect

Tags: iis, redirect, web-config

I have a .net site on a shared host environment so I don't have access to other solutions that require access to the server.

If I put the following code in my current web.config, is it enough to do the 301 redirect to my-new-site.com? Thanks.

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.my-new-site.com/" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: When you say "enough" are you talking about SEO or just about getting users to the correct site?

Comment: @kheld I only try to avoid the SEO problem of duplicate content. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Redirection is not available on the default installation of IIS 7. You have to add it in `Common Http Features` for the  Web Server Role. Is it enabled on your shared host ?

The correct way to do a permanent 301 redirect is :

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.my-new-site.com/" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
</system.webServer>
```

the default is response status is 302 (Found). More infos [here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect).

Comment: I have no access to the server so cannot add anything to the WSR or know if it's enabled.

Comment: I will assume the feature is enabled and try your solution, which after reading the linked page you provided, seems to be the correct way. Thanks.